# How to view detailed error message in failed build

Tags: npm, bitrise

[image]

So this is the only thing I see on failed build. When running npm scripts on a cli, you usually see more than the exit status. Is there some option to view the entire cli output instead of this pseudo log?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I contacted support and was told to cat the debug log in order to see the output.

```
#!/bin/bash 
set -ex 
cat $(find $HOME/.npm/_logs -name '*-debug.log')
```